# W540 docking in Mint freezes

Tags: linux, linux-mint, docking-station

I have got Lenovo w540 and running Mint 16. When I dock the laptop into the docking station, everything freezes, including the laptop's own keyboard. How should I go along about finding out what is wrong?

Seems like it understands that it has been inserted into a ThinkPad Dock:

```
[  537.648571] usb 3-9: Product: Lenovo ThinkPad Dock   
[  537.648577] usb 3-9: Manufacturer: LENOVO                 
[  537.649402] hub 3-9:1.0: USB hub found
[  537.649696] hub 3-9:1.0: 4 ports detected
[  537.939319] usb 3-9.2: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[  537.958157] usb 3-9.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b
[  537.958168] usb 3-9.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  537.958175] usb 3-9.2: Product: USB Receiver
[  537.958181] usb 3-9.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[  537.964487] thinkpad_acpi: EC reports that Thermal Table has changed
[  537.965034] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0010: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-9.2/input2
[  537.967751] input: Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:101a as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-9/3-9.2/3-9.2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0010/input/input17
[  537.968177] logitech-djdevice 0003:046D:C52B.0011: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:101a] on usb-0000:00:14.0-9.2:1
[  538.047113] usb 3-9.3: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
[  538.065951] usb 3-9.3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b
[  538.065953] usb 3-9.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  538.065954] usb 3-9.3: Product: USB Receiver
[  538.065955] usb 3-9.3: Manufacturer: Logitech
[  538.071609] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0014: hiddev0,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-9.3/input2
[  538.155070] usb 3-9.4: new high-speed USB device number 15 using xhci_hcd
[  538.171156] usb 3-9.4: New USB device found, idVendor=17ef, idProduct=100f
[  538.171158] usb 3-9.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  538.171160] usb 3-9.4: Product: Lenovo ThinkPad Dock
[  538.171162] usb 3-9.4: Manufacturer: Lenovo
[  538.171163] usb 3-9.4: SerialNumber: Rev1.2
[  538.171636] hub 3-9.4:1.0: USB hub found
[  538.171702] hub 3-9.4:1.0: 3 ports detected
[  538.235051] systemd-udevd[2968]: failed to execute '/lib/udev/mtp-probe' 'mtp-probe /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-9/3-9.2 3 13': No such file or directory
[  538.442637] usb 3-9.4.1: new full-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[  538.462367] usb 3-9.4.1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b
[  538.462369] usb 3-9.4.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  538.462371] usb 3-9.4.1: Product: USB Receiver
[  538.462372] usb 3-9.4.1: Manufacturer: Logitech
[  538.472456] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0017: hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11
```

Is it correct that docking is recognized as USB? The whole log file is here: http://pastebin.com/CTkKv0NS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually related to the monitor not being recognized (or something else related to the graphics). See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/778920).

What worked for me: upgraded my mint to 17 and now the freeze-problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

From the above output, it looks like you are missing the libmtp-runtime package:

```
  sudo apt-get install libmtp-runtime
```

I understand that it is not, strictly speaking, a dependency of udev, thus it may not be installed on some systems (it is on mine). You may give it a try.

Should that alone not completely solve your problem, you may also try installing the *pmount* package, which allows you to mount disks as if you were root, even when there is no suitable entry in */etc/fstab*. You can find a good description of that [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB#Using_pmount):

```
  sudo apt-get install pmount
```

Comment: I have tried installing both packages but I can't get it working. Is it correct that docking is recognized as USB? I have the whole log here: http://pastebin.com/CTkKv0NS