# Thinkad w540 docking station and Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, docking-station, xrandr

I have got Lenovo Thinkpad w540 and running Mint 16. When I dock the laptop into the docking station, everything freezes. I have to undock and wait until the login window is loaded. How should I go along about finding out what is wrong?

What I found out so far was the following. I ran the `xrandr` command before and after docking and there are differences. Is this causing me the problem?
Without docking and the external monitor connected directly to the laptop:

```
$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080      60.1*+   59.9  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1200      60.0 +
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9
```

When docked, the external monitor is connected through the docking station:

```
$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080      60.1*+   59.9  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected 1920x1200+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1200      60.0 +
   1920x1080      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        60.0  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

If I try to run this command:

```
xrandr --auto --output DP2 --mode 1920x1200 && xrandr --auto --output eDP1 --mode 1920x1080 --left-of DP2
```

The screen freezes again and I have to switch off the laptop. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The user who answered the question and then deleted the answer was actually right.

Upgraded my mint to `17` and now the freeze-problem is gone.